# Any Idea on How Word Wrap css interpreted by browser?

Tags: css

I was wondering if for `word-wrap: break-word` the browsers first check whether the word is in a dictionary and then wrap it together.

Can any one help me understanding how word-wrap css work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the specifications will answer your question : 
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-word-wrap

There is also an article about it on css-tricks : 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/